# How can JVM arguments be passed to apps started through java webstart in MacOS?

Tags: java, macos

We have a application which is triggered from browser. This application consumes around 800 mb of memory. This works perfectly when invoked from any browsers in windows OS. The same application when triggered from MacOS throws an out of memory exception which occurs when the application is short of memory. Is there any way to increase the memory allocated for apps running in mac os environment. Also please let me know how JVM arguments can be passed to apps started through java webstart in macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [JNLP file syntax](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jws/developersguide/syntax.html). You can use a **j2se** element inside a **resources** element to pass arguments to the VM.

Example code:

```
<resources>
  <j2se version="1.5+" initial-heap-size="64m" max-heap-size="512m" java-vm-args=""/>
</resources>
```

You can also specify an **os** attribute to your **resources** element, if you want to handle things differently on different platforms.